# last 6 months total in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have to calculate total quantity sold for last 6 months. For example in case of January 2018 , I have to calculate told quantity sold from July - Dec 2017. This total should be grouped by primary key.

Thanks

Primary Key Date    qty     last 6 months quantity sold

1          1-Oct    4   0

1          1-Nov    10  4

1           5-Dec   20  14

1          1-Jan    3   34

1          1-Sep    88  0

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the range using ADD_MONTHS plus TRUNC:

```
WHERE datecole BETWEEN Trunc(Add_Months(Current_Date, -6), 'mon')
                   AND Trunc(Current_Date, 'mon') -1
```